# framework best for migrating an existing donation website to a php framework?

Tags: php, frameworks, migration

which framework would be best to migrate an existing donation processing php website to a php framework ?? 
please provide some justifications for your answer ..

Three frameworks are in my mind : CakePHP, CodeIgniter, Yii

Comment: or, symfony, or symfony2, or ZendFramework, or ZendFramework2, ...

Comment: sorry forgot to mention Zend :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cakephp and yii have PDO implemented.
I'll use YII, i love the way it implements the stuffs.
Generate migration using command line.. crud using web interface (so easy).
You can add foreign keys on your migration.. his support to database is larger than the cake php.
The model methods and pdo are so easy to work with, it have a lot of examples.

Cake php is sweet too, but Yii have more things and is more advanced.
The default scaffold on yii is better, advanced search implemented and jquery on the fly

Comment: a) _PHP_ has PDO directly integrated. No need to implement it b) ZF1, ZF2, Symfony2 (Doctrine2) and (I guess) Symfony1 make use of PDO too.